# Delete multiple worksheets if they exist in a workbook

Tags: excel, vba, delete-file

```
Sub DeleteSheetsIfExists()
    Dim sheetName As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim sheetToDelete As Worksheet
    Dim found As Boolean
   
    ' List of sheet names to be deleted
    sheetName = Array("Summary", "Summary (1)", "Summary (2)", "Summary (3)", "Summary (4)", "Summary (5)", "Summary (6)", "Summary (7)", "Summary (8)", "Summary (9)", "Summary (10)", "Summary (11)", "Summary (12)", "Summary (13)", "Summary (14)", "Summary (15)", "Summary (16)", "Summary (17)", "Summary (18)", "Summary (19)", "Summary (20)", "Summary (21)", "Summary (22)", "Summary (23)", "Summary (24)", "Summary (25)", "Summary (26)")
   
    For Each sheetToDelete In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        found = False
       
        For i = LBound(sheetName) To UBound(sheetName)
            If sheetName(i) = sheetToDelete.Name Then
                found = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
       
        If found Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' Disable alerts
            sheetToDelete.Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True ' Enable alerts
        End If
    Next sheetToDelete
End Sub
```

This is my code, but sometimes code works and sometimes it doesn't work at all.
Can you please help me why doesn't it work sometimes.

I was expecting sheet name "Summary" or "Summary (3) or any other sheet with summary in it to be deleted.

Comment: `sometimes it doesn't work at all` - what does not work? Any error messages? Step through your code and see what happens, with focus on the inner For loop.

Comment: Instead of looping through all possible variants of Summary..., why don't you just check `If sheetToDelete.name like "Summary*" Then`?

Comment: No error messages pop up.
I will try if statement, but I don't think it will work.

Comment: I think there is a problem, the excel already contains Macros. I think they are not letting me run this formula. Maybe variable is same, if I do insert a new module in this workbook it works. But whenever I try to insert new module within the same Macro that's imbedded in Excel it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

### Delete Existing Worksheets

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteExistingWorkSheets()
    
    Const BEGINS_WITH As String = "Summary"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If InStr(1, ws.Name, BEGINS_WITH, vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' delete without confirmation
                ws.Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
    Next ws
        
End Sub
```